# CKEditor ignores tags which have classes

Tags: ckeditor

If the source of something I write in my CKEDITOR looks like this:

```
This is my text.  <strong>This part is bold.</strong>  This part isn't.
```

I can highlight the bolded part and unbold it by pressing CTRL+B.  However, if I add a class to that strong tag (due to another plugin I'm working on), I can only unbold clean strong tags - no attributes, styles, or classes.  For example, consider this scenario:

```
This is my text.  <strong>This part is bold.</strong>  This part isn't.  <strong class="whatever">This part is bolded AND has a custom class.</strong>
```

Only the first bolded segmented will be unbolded - the 2nd is pretty much stuck as is until I remove the ".whatever" class.  Is there any way to get it to ignore strong tags with classes, and just do them regardless of what other attributes they have?  I'm guessing it has to do with that "Advanced Content Filter" or something, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

After much hairpulling, I (think) I have the answer.  In the CKEDITOR style definition, an applied style (ex, a strong tag) needs to have all of its attributes parsed through the content filter.  If an attribute that is not dealt with by this filter remains when it comes time to actually remove the textNode from the style tags and replace it back into the parent element, [the tags (and thus the style) will NOT be removed if there are any attributes remaining on the element](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/style.js#L1312).  There is a (very poorly) documented workaround to this: the alwaysRemoveElement property can be [set to true on the style DEFINITION](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style-property-alwaysRemoveElement) (why the definition, and not the style itself, I have no idea).

Long story short, a little snippet of code that will force the removal of all style tags, even if their attributes don't match exactly with the filter.  Hopefully it doesn't cause bugs somewhere else...

```
//this = Your Editor Instance
this.data.editor.on( 'instanceReady', function(){

    //Filter through the existing contentRules, looking for styleCommands
    $.each(this.activeFilter.allowedContent, function(i,v) {
        var name = v.featureName, command = this.commands[v.featureName];
        if (name && command && command.contentForms && command.style) {
            command.style._.definition.alwaysRemoveElement = true;
        }
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer, just add this in the config:

```
CKEDITOR.config.coreStyles_bold : { element: 'strong', overrides: 'b' ,alwaysRemoveElement: true},
```

It was also difficult for me to find this workaround, in my case I was adding an id to the strong element.